# Как отправить запрос API Яндекс кассы?

Tags: python, яндекс-касса

На сайте один товар и используется яндекс кассы. сайт на flask. 
Создаю платеж, как сказано в документации

```
payment = Payment.create({
    "amount": {
        "value": "100.00",
        "currency": "RUB"
    },
    "confirmation": {
        "type": "redirect",
        "return_url": "https://www.merchant-website.com/return_url"
    },
    "capture": True,
    "description": "Заказ №1"
}, uuid.uuid4())
```

а куда его отправлять?

Не сталкивался с самописными сайтами с оплатой, поэтому возможно кому то покажется глупым вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Можно посмотреть в примерах curl например

```
curl https://payment.yandex.net/api/v3/payments \
  -X POST \
  -u <Идентификатор магазина>:<Секретный ключ> \
  -H 'Idempotence-Key: <Ключ идемпотентности>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
        "amount": {
          "value": "2.00",
          "currency": "RUB"
        },
        "payment_method_data": {
          "type": "bank_card"
        },
        "confirmation": {
          "type": "redirect",
          "return_url": "https://www.merchant-website.com/return_url"
        },
        "description": "Заказ №72"
      }'
```

Урл на который отправляется запрос
https://payment.yandex.net/api/v3/payments

А вообще для Python есть API Яндекс кассы и не нужно делать какие либо запросы

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(request):
payment = Payment.create({
    "amount": {
        "value": "100.00",
        "currency": "RUB"
    },
    "confirmation": {
        "type": "redirect",
        "return_url": "https://www.merchant-website.com/return_url"
    },
    "capture": True,
    "description": "Заказ №1"
}, uuid.uuid4())

return redirect(payment.confirmation.confirmation_url)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]